# How can I control wrapanel so if I removed an item the order doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

In a `listview`, I am using `Wrappanel` as  `ItemsPanelTemplate`

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItemViewModels}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Drop="Card_Drop"
    AllowDrop="True"
    DragLeave="Card_DragLeave"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Disable, ElementName=root}"
    Background="Green">

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>


    <!-- Displaying Cards in CardCollection View -->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>            
            <Border BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="BlanchedAlmond" 
                Opacity="1"
                Background="BlanchedAlmond"
                Width="25" Height="30"
                MouseMove="Card_MouseMove"
                CornerRadius="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cardstr}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Foreground="{Binding Cardclr}"
                    Background="BlanchedAlmond" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

[before removing an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAbP3.png)

How can I fix the `Listview`, so if I removed an item there would be an empty slot in its place instead of the list getting rearranged like in the following img:
[after removing an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa8T5.png)

I tried `Wrapanel` and `Gridview` both are not working properly.
I don't want to insert cell by cell in a grid as it will complicate the program

Comment: you likely need to replace the removed card by a placeholder for 'empty card'. Actually, the panels behave right. They display the items as they appear in the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the card from the source collection, you should set a property of it to indicate that you want to display another template for that particular card.

You could for example add an `IsEmpty` property to your class that contains the `Cardstr` and `Cardclr` properties and then use `ContentControl` with a `DataTrigger` to dynamically change the template:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItemViewModels}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Drop="Card_Drop"
    AllowDrop="True"
    DragLeave="Card_DragLeave"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Disable, ElementName=root}"
    Background="Green">

    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="cardTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="2"
                 BorderBrush="BlanchedAlmond" 
                 Opacity="1"
                 Background="BlanchedAlmond"
                 Width="25" Height="30"
                 MouseMove="Card_MouseMove"
                 CornerRadius="5"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cardstr}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Foreground="{Binding Cardclr}"
                     Background="BlanchedAlmond" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="emptyTemplate">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock>empty...</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource cardTemplate}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEmpty}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource emptyTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

</ListView>
```

Make sure that your class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class Card : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    private bool _isEmpty;
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return _isEmpty; }
        set { _isEmpty = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then you simply set the `IsEmpty` property of the item that you want to "remove".